# How I can transform GEOGRAPHY exemplar from one coordinate system to another in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, spatial, coordinate-transformation, srid

How I can transform GEOGRAPHY exemplar from one coordinate system to another in MS SQL Server?

For example, I have:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(3 3)', 4326)
```

How I can transform this GEOGRAPHY to coordinate system with SRID = 4120?

Comment: Think you'll need to convert it to another form then to the required SRID something like


    `DECLARE @g geography;`
    `SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(3 3)', 4326)`
    `SELECT geography::STGeomFromWKB( geography::STGeomFromWKB(@g.STAsBinary(), @g.STSrid).STAsBinary(),4120 ) `

Comment: I need not just change SRIDs. I need to recount coordinates in new coordinate system

Comment: In short you cannot do this in SQL.  Matt kind of covers this (although you could simplify the transformation to `SELECT geography::STGeomFromWKB(@g.STAsBinary(), 4120);`).  To reproject you will need to use Third Party tools to make the unit conversion.

Comment: Jon Bellamy, do you mean SQL Server Spatial Tool?

Comment: LongLat coordinates are the same between [4326](http://epsg.io/4326) and [4120](http://epsg.io/4120). The datums are different, but that shouldn't shift the coordinates.